# Selecting images inside a form using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got some server side PHP code that dynamically displays thumbnails of all the images contained in a directory:

```
<form>
  <input type="hidden" name="animal"> 
  <div id="thumbs">
\\ Dynamically created thumbnails start
    <img src="images/bat.jpg">
    <img src="images/cat.jpg">
    <img src="images/rat.jpg">
\\ Dynamically created thumbnails end
  </div>
</form>
```

I want the correct jQuery syntax so that when a user clicks on one of the images it:

- Removes border styles from all of the thumbnails
- Highlights the selected thumbnail by adding a coloured border
- Changes the value of the form field "animal" to the file name shown in the image.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: What is meant by "clears formatting"?

Comment: Sorry, "remove border styles" would be more accurate. Will attempt to edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "removes formatting on thumbnails" means removing all css on your images, then I think what you want is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ML78Z/).

Answer (score 2):

***demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9rFKB/***

jquery

```
$('#thumbs').delegate('img', 'click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    // Clear formatting
    $('#thumbs img').removeClass('border-highlight');

    // Highlight with coloured border
    $this.addClass('border-highlight');

    // Changes the value of the form field "animal" to the file name shown in the image.
    $('[name="animal"]').val( $this.attr('src').substring($this.attr('src').lastIndexOf('/')+1) );
    alert( $('[name="animal"]').val() );
});
```

css

```
.border-highlight {
    border:5px dashed red;   
}
```

I've used `delegate` instead of `click` since you have stated that the images are to be created dynamically.